# Django - Problems with get_or_create()

Tags: python, django

I'm facing problems using get_or_create() in my view.
What I want to do is have the User get or create an instance of the Keyword model whenever he wants to add a keyword.

I have a Keyword model that looks like this:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, default=None)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.keywords
```

I have a form to create the keyword:

```
class KeywordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    keywords = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(KeywordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["keywords"].unique = False

    class Meta:
        fields = ("keywords",)
        model = models.Keyword
```

I've tried different things in the view and here is my current version, without the use of get_or_create. It only creates the keyword:

```
class KeywordCreationView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.KeywordForm
    model = models.Keyword
    page_title = 'Add a new keyword'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")
    template_name = "accounts/add_keyword.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        var = super(KeywordCreationView, self).form_valid(form)

        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        self.object.members.add(self.object.user)

        return var
```

How should my view look in order to get the keyword if it exists and if it does, add the User as 'member'. If it doesn't, create the Keyword.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe CreateView isn't the right class for this. You should use [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) instead and override the [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method (which is actually a part of the SingleObjectMixin) ancestor of this class based view.

The [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L22) of this mixin is rather daunging but in your case something as simple as

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    if queryset:
        obj, c = queryset.get_or_create(pk=pk)

    else:
        obj, c = MyModel.get_or_create(pk=pk)

    return obj
```

might work. But frankly, it's alot simpler to use a simple (non class based view)

Comment: Hi, sorry it took me so long to answer. I didn't manage to make it work with your answer. But you did guide me in the right direction: I ended up abandoning the Class Based View and went for a simple (non classed based view). And it worked - so much easier too to be honest. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am no fan of class based views either.